# Hide or change the position of the Bing.Maps MapType selector

Tags: winrt-xaml, bing-maps

I'm using the Bing.Maps SDK for Windows 8.1 (Version 1.313.825.0 from 2014-02-05, according to Visual Studio the extension manager) to display a map.

I'd like to move the MapType selection control:

[image: MapType/Traffic selection control of the Bing.Map]

The control is shown in the upper left corner. I would like to move it to another corner or hide it altogether.

The map has properties that allow positioning the logo, copyright and legend. However, I could not find a configuration setting that allows moving or hiding this control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set:

`ShowNavigationBar="False"`

Comment: While NavigationBar is a weird name for the thing, I'm wondering how I've missed that... :/